# search map for part of a tuple as key

Tags: c++, search, maps, equals, unordered-map

Is it possible to search a map for all key,value pairs that contains part of a tuple in C++

For example, I have an unordered multimap that uses a tuple of  as a key, but I want to look for a tuple of:
<"abc", doesn't matter, doesn't matter>

I've looked at the equals range and equals function, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for.  I'm pretty sure I could just iterate through the entire map using a ranged for loop, but I'd rather not do that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since tuple generates a hash using all the objects its storing you cant do this with just the original map.  You could do:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::tuple< /*type here*/  > *> mapToMap;
```

Which you can use to store another map which you can use to lookup the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `std::for_each` to perform a linear search on your map.

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    using MyTuple = std::tuple<std::string, int, int>;
    std::multimap<MyTuple, int> myMultimap;

    myMultimap.emplace(std::make_tuple("abc", 0, 0), 0);
    myMultimap.emplace(std::make_tuple("abc", 1, 5), 1);
    myMultimap.emplace(std::make_tuple("abc", 4, 2), 2);
    myMultimap.emplace(std::make_tuple("bbb", 0, 0), 3);
    myMultimap.emplace(std::make_tuple("ccc", 0, 0), 4);

    std::vector<int> searchResult;

    std::for_each(myMultimap.begin(), myMultimap.end(), 
        [&searchResult](std::pair<const MyTuple, int>& element)
    {
        if (std::get<0>(element.first).compare("abc") == 0)
        {
            searchResult.push_back(element.second);
        }
    });

    for (auto key : searchResult)
    {
        std::cout << key << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code will print:

```
0
1
2
```